# Were the Gopikas and Srimati Radharani blond-haired?

Tags: puranas, krishna, radha

How is the physical description of them given in the Puranas?

Comment: this is kinda funny tbh. Why would they be blond haired? Do you see anyone naturally blonde haired in the areas of UP or let alone that, in the whole of current day India?